# List comprehension assignment/comparison fails after 256

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

I tried to find the performance difference between slice assignment and regular assignment for lists. Here is the code:

```
import time

N =  1000  
a = list(range(N))
b = list(range(N))

time1 = time.time()
for i in range(N):
    a = [x for x in a if x is not i]
time2 = time.time()
for i in range(N):
    b[:] = [x for x in b if x is not i]
time3 = time.time()

print a
print b    
print time2 - time1
print time3 - time2
```

My expectation is that, for each list `a` and `b`, this will remove one element at a time, so that `print a` and `print b` both print empty lists. Instead, they seem to always print the starting lists, but with the first `256` elements missing.

They both print:

```
[257, 258, 259 ... N-1]
```

What is happening?

I'm using Python 2.7.6.

Comment: Because small integers are cached in CPython, use `!=` not `is` operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `is` instead of `==`.

The former checks for object *identity*, not equality. There's no reason to believe that evaluating, say, `300+1` twice will give you the same `int` object, just that they'll both give you `int` objects whose value is `301`.

This happens to "work" for numbers up to 256 because your particular Python implementation<sup>*</sup> happens to intern integers up to 256. At startup, it creates a singleton object for the number `1`, a singleton object for `2`, and so on. Any time an expression evaluates to the number `1`, it gives you that object, instead of a new one.<sup>**</sup>

Needless to say, you should not rely on that optimization.

---

<sub>* IIRC, every version of CPython from the 1.x days to 3.5 defaults to this behavior for all integers from -5 to 256, but you can change those limits, or turn off the feature, at build time, and a different implementation might do something different.</sub>

<sub>** If you're wondering how this works in CPython, at the C API level, [`PyLong_FromLong`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong) does this by looking up numbers from -5 to 256 in an array of singleton values. You can see the 3.4 version of the code, for example, [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Objects/longobject.c#l230); the macro `CHECK_SMALL_INT` and the actual function `get_small_int` that it calls, and the static array that function uses, are all are in the same file, up near the top.</sub>